# Query filter for searching rollup index works with epoch time fails with date math

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

`How do we query (filter) a rollup index?

For example, based on the query [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rollup-getting-started.html)

Request:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "timeline": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "fixed_interval": "7d"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nodes": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "node"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max_temperature": {
              "max": {
                "field": "temperature"
              }
            },
            "avg_voltage": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "voltage"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
   "took" : 93,
   "timed_out" : false,
   "terminated_early" : false,
   "_shards" : ... ,
   "hits" : {
     "total" : {
        "value": 0,
        "relation": "eq"
     },
     "max_score" : 0.0,
     "hits" : [ ]
   },
   "aggregations" : {
     "timeline" : {
       "buckets" : [
         {
           "key_as_string" : "2018-01-18T00:00:00.000Z",
           "key" : 1516233600000,
           "doc_count" : 6,
           "nodes" : {
             "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
             "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
             "buckets" : [
               {
                 "key" : "a",
                 "doc_count" : 2,
                 "max_temperature" : {
                   "value" : 202.0
                 },
                 "avg_voltage" : {
                   "value" : 5.1499998569488525
                 }
               },
               {
                 "key" : "b",
                 "doc_count" : 2,
                 "max_temperature" : {
                   "value" : 201.0
                 },
                 "avg_voltage" : {
                   "value" : 5.700000047683716
                 }
               },
               {
                 "key" : "c",
                 "doc_count" : 2,
                 "max_temperature" : {
                   "value" : 202.0
                 },
                 "avg_voltage" : {
                   "value" : 4.099999904632568
                 }
               }
             ]
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

How to filter say last 3 days,  is it possible?

For a test case, I used fixed_interval rate of 1m (one minute, and also 60 minutes) and I tried the following and the error was all query shards failed.  Is it possible to query filter rollup agggregations?

Test Query for searching rollup index

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-3d/d",
        "lt": "now/d"
      }
    }
  }
  "aggregations": {
    "timeline": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "fixed_interval": "7d"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nodes": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "node"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max_temperature": {
              "max": {
                "field": "temperature"
              }
            },
            "avg_voltage": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "voltage"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're using `@timestamp` in your query and `timestamp` in your aggregation?

Comment: @Val fixed the query (to timestamp), the problem I am having is if I use epoch time I am getting results back however, date math ("gte": "now-3d/d",    "lte": "now/d") way of filtering is not working.

Comment: Can you look at your mapping and check the type of the `timestamp` field? Do you confirm it's of type `date`?

Comment: @Val original index has default mapping.  As Date Math query aggregation worked on original index I assumed that Rollup index would also be working.  

Given that date_histogram bucket keys are in epoch is there a way to use key_as_string for searching or when we define Rollup index is there a way to specify bucket keys to have date type instead of epoch?

Comment: Can you show the mapping of your rollup index?